# For baking, is there a common "done" temperature across different kinds of breads?

Tags: baking

I'm pretty new to baking, and it seems like the toothpick test is pretty subjective.  I'm wondering, can I use my Thermapen instead?

At a fundamental level, are all breads "done" at a certain temperature, or are sweetbreads done baking at one temperature, yeast breads at another, etc?  Is it common enough among recipes to have a chart, like for beef/chicken/pork/etc?

Or is it totally all over the map based on the recipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how "heavy" your bread is. White bread is done at around 202 - 205 degrees Fahrenheit. Darker bread, 208 - 212. And definitely use the Thermapen if you have one. There is no point in guessing if you don't have to.

Comment: +1 on the temperature ranges AND the confirmation on the Thermapen...or any instant read thermometer.  I use mine every time I make bread.

Comment: I always pull any baked good out before 210. It's going to keep building tempture after it comes out of the oven for a few minutes and after 212 degrees you start loosing moisture and the bread starts to dry out.